# Do asynchronous OPFS operations complete on document close?

Tags: javascript, html5-filesystem

In the [origin-private file system API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API#origin_private_file_system), everything is basically asynchronous. You can get a synchronous handle for reading, writing or truncating a file, but it still passes through a `Promise`.

Documents are immediately closed in the browser. Is there any guarantee that an active handle whose `Promise` is not yet resolved will continue until it's used for writing to a game save file? For example, can the developer do FS operations in the [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) event and will the browser keep the document finishing its process in the background until there's no active FS promise?

Comment: I think there are no guarantees for unloading whatsoever